# Creating a multiple class instances from user input

Tags: c++, class, instance, cin

I was wondering if it was possible to create multiple class instances solely from a user input. For example:

```
Class Person{
       int a;
       int b;

}

Person 1; Person 2; etc...
int number;
```

Then

```
cout << "Ask user to input a number for amount of class instances";
cin >> number;
```

Is there any way that when you ask the user for that number, you get lets say 5 class instances of person? Or is this not do-able in this form and perhaps another approach should be taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin >> number;
std::vector<Person> instances(number); // will use Person() default constructor
                                       // to create number of instances
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<Person> persons;
```

You can insert as many Person objects as you want using `std::vector::push_back()`

Comment: as we have not done vector, I am unsure of the use of it. What exactly does the vector functionality do?

Comment: Think of a vector as a dynamic array that will resize to accomodate the elements you insert into it.

Comment: he can allocate space in advance since number of instances is known

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 11 this is very simple via Dynamic Runtime sized arrays.

```
Person people[number];
```

All of the vector answers are also correct and in my opinion superior.